# How do I check if all elements of an array are greater than zero C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, c++11

I am fairly new to C++ and I am trying to make a loop that has a check in it that needs to go like this:

"if all the elements in the array are greater than zero, break the loop, if they are not then restart the loop from the beginning"

Please could you help me as I have no idea how to begin

Thanks guys

Comment: So if your array has a non-positive element, you loop forever? Also, what have you tried so far? Any C++ tutorial will introduce loops approximately 7 minutes in.

Comment: The algorithm you described does not do what the title suggests. Which one of them are you actually trying to realize?

Comment: if it loops then the array alters some of its variables, I just need a way to check them all at once

Comment: `std::all_of(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](int a){return a>0;}`

Answer (score 5):

Use [*`std::all_of`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of), or sisters for whatever logic you have  <sub>I don't know about its correctness</sub>

```
while ( !std::all_of( std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [](int i){ return i > 0; }) )
{
  /* if all the elements in the array are greater than zero, 
     break the loop, 
     if they are not then restart the loop from the beginning
  */

}
```

Comment: Note: this is C++11 stuff only (just in case)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
[loop]{
  bool negative_found = false;
  for(... each element in array...){
    if(elem_val < 0){
      negative_found = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(negative_found){
    continue;
  }else{
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you should paste your own loop definitions.

Comment: what is [loop] supposed to do?

Comment: I think that there is a global loop, that we should break if there are no negative elements in the array.

Comment: And this fantasy is based on...?

Comment: "if all the elements in the array are greater than zero, break the **loop**"